# Twilio video JavaScript, calling track.disable() from Safari reloads the page

Tags: javascript, safari, twilio, twilio-video

I have developed a video calling feature using twilio video javascript, everything works fine but when user mutes the video from Safari browser on mac OS, the page reloads automatically showing an error *This web page was reloaded because a problem occured.*
Below is the function called when audio / video is muted/unmuted:

`toggleMedia("video");`

```
function toggleMedia(mediaType) {
            try {
                console.log("toggleMedia");
                if (!window.room) return;
                var localMedia = window.room.localParticipant;
                localMedia.tracks.forEach(function (publication) {
                    if (publication.kind === mediaType) {                        
                        if (publication.isTrackEnabled) {
                            publication.track.disable();
                        } else {
                            publication.track.enable();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
```

I am trying to avoid publish, unpublish track approach. What is wrong with track.disable() on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I also faced this problem! This error is already listed in the list of [Common Issues](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/blob/master/COMMON_ISSUES.md).

The error only appears when using the H264 codec, so you can use the VP8 codec as a temporary solution:

```
import TwilioVideo from 'twilio-video';

await TwilioVideo.connect(token, {
  name,
  preferredVideoCodecs: [ 'VP8' ]
});
```

In my case, the code looks like this:

```
connect(authHelper.getUserVideoChatToken()?.token, { 
        name:'testRoom', 
        audio: true, 
        video: { facingMode: { exact: (isUsingFrontCamera ? 'environment' : 'user') } }, 
        preferredVideoCodecs: ['VP8'] 
}).then(...)
```